# Calculating Hertz depending on what note

Tags: rust, audio

I'm working on a sample player and need help regarding pitch shifting in rust.

The base frequency of my sample is 44kHz, and the note of the input sample is 60 (middle c, i'm using the midi range from 1 to 127).

Is there some formula in rust which can calculate the new frequency?

This formula doesn't calculate it, it's just a visualization to what I'm trying to achieve

```rust
fn calc(note: usize) -> f32 {
    let difference = note-60;
    // return the new frequency
    return 44000  ......
}
```

Comment: The sample rate is equals to the pitch, if you speed up the sample rate, and keep the output sample rate the same, the sound plays faster, thus higher. If I haven't clarified enough, I'm talking about a phase vocoder system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in frequency is a factor of `2 ^ N/12` where `N` is the difference in semitones. An octave below (-12 semitones) would mean half the frequency and an octave above (+12 semitones) would mean double the frequency.

In Rust you could express that (with a base frequency of 44k) as such ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3c7726dc20c21128eb261944cdd5633)):

```
fn calc(difference: i32) -> f32 {
    44000.0 * f32::powf(2.0, (difference as f32) / 12.0)
}
```